# In iOS 10.1 camera function is crashing. but it's working fine in iOS 9.3 and below

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I'm new to objective c and iOS.
 In my project i wrote code for camera It's working fine in iOS 9.3 and below. but it's crashing in iOS 10.1.

I have created previewView like this

```
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet AVCamPreviewView *previewView;
```

and i have created session and setting session like this

```
    // Check for device authorization
    [self checkDeviceAuthorizationStatus];


    // Create the AVCaptureSession
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [self setSession:session];

   // Setup the preview view
   [[self previewView] setSession:session];
```

After calling setSession method It's getting crash in below method

```
    - (void)setSession:(AVCaptureSession *)session
{
   [(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[self layer] setSession: session];
}
```

and I have took camera permission also like

```
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow us to scan documents and capture images.</string>
```

in plist file. please help me .....
this is my code  CustomCameraViewController.m file

```
  #import "CustomCameraViewController.h"
  #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
  #import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
  #import "PhotoEditViewController.h"
  #import "QuackPostData.h"
  #import "AVCamPreviewView.h"
  #import "Constants.h"
  #import <Photos/Photos.h>


  static void * CapturingStillImageContext =  &CapturingStillImageContext;
  static void * RecordingContext = &RecordingContext;
  static void * SessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorizedContext = &SessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorizedContext;

  @interface CustomCameraViewController ()    <UINavigationControllerDelegate,          UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>
 {
    BOOL isFromEditView;
 }

     @property (nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;

    // For use in the storyboards.
     @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet AVCamPreviewView *previewView;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *cameraButton;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *stillButton;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *flashButton;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *photosButton;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *cancelButton;

  - (IBAction)changeCamera:(id)sender;
  - (IBAction)snapStillImage:(id)sender;
  - (IBAction)cancelButtonTouched:(id)sender;
  - (IBAction)photoButtonTouched:(id)sender;
  - (IBAction)flashButtonTouched:(id)sender;


    // Session management.
     @property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t sessionQueue; // Communicate with the session and other session objects on this queue.
     @property (nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *session;
     @property (nonatomic) AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoDeviceInput;
     @property (nonatomic) AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieFileOutput;
     @property (nonatomic) AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;

    // Utilities.
         @property (nonatomic) UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundRecordingID;
         @property (nonatomic, getter = isDeviceAuthorized) BOOL deviceAuthorized;
         @property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = isSessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorized) BOOL sessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorized;
         @property (nonatomic) BOOL lockInterfaceRotation;
         @property (nonatomic) id runtimeErrorHandlingObserver;

        @end


   @implementation CustomCameraViewController

     - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
   {
      self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (self) {
      // Custom initialization
     }
       return self;
   }


   - (BOOL)isSessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorized
 {
      return [[self session] isRunning] && [self isDeviceAuthorized];
 }

  + (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingSessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorized
 {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"session.running", @"deviceAuthorized", nil];
 }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];


//adding border to photo button
   CALayer * layer = [_photosButton layer];
   [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
   [layer setCornerRadius:0.0]; //when radius is 0, the border is a rectangle
    [layer setBorderWidth:0.5];
     [layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];


// Assign Nil and fresh 
   [QuackPostData Instance].quack_NewImage = NO ;
   [QuackPostData Instance].quack_Image = nil;



// Create the AVCaptureSession
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [self setSession:session];

// Setup the preview view
    [[self previewView] setSession:session];

// Check for device authorization
    [self checkDeviceAuthorizationStatus];

     [self setLatestPhoto:[self photosButton]];

    [self customFontPrepare];




     dispatch_queue_t sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("session queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    [self setSessionQueue:sessionQueue];


    dispatch_async(sessionQueue, ^{
        [self setBackgroundRecordingID:UIBackgroundTaskInvalid];

        NSError *error = nil;

        AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [CustomCameraViewController deviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferringPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
            AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoDeviceInput =   [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:&error];


    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }

    if ([session canAddInput:videoDeviceInput])
    {
        [session addInput:videoDeviceInput];
        [self setVideoDeviceInput:videoDeviceInput];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self previewView]).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
            ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self previewView]).bounds = ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self previewView]).bounds;
        //
            [[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] setVideoOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)[self interfaceOrientation]];
        });
    }

    AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [[AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] firstObject];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }

    if ([session canAddInput:audioDeviceInput])
    {
        [session addInput:audioDeviceInput];
    }

    AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
    if ([session canAddOutput:movieFileOutput])
    {
        [[self session] startRunning];
        [session addOutput:movieFileOutput];
        AVCaptureConnection *connection = [movieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if ([connection isVideoStabilizationSupported])
            [connection setEnablesVideoStabilizationWhenAvailable:YES];
        [self setMovieFileOutput:movieFileOutput];
    }

    AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    if ([session canAddOutput:stillImageOutput])
    {
        [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:@{AVVideoCodecKey :    AVVideoCodecJPEG}];
        [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];
        [self setStillImageOutput:stillImageOutput];
    }
});
   }
```

and  AVCamPreviewView.m file

```
 #import "AVCamPreviewView.h"
 #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
 #import <Photos/Photos.h>
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @implementation AVCamPreviewView

+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer class];
}

     - (AVCaptureSession *)session
   {
        return [(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[self layer] session];
    }

     - (void)setSession:(AVCaptureSession *)session
    {

      [(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[self layer] setSession: session];

     }
    @end
```

AVCamPreviewView.h file

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @class AVCaptureSession;

 @interface AVCamPreviewView : UIView

 @property (nonatomic,retain) AVCaptureSession *session;

 @end
```

Comment: what msg you are getting when crashed?

Comment: @Gonesh k r what message you getting in log?

Comment: In this line "[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[self layer] setSession: session]; " I'm getting like "thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code = 1, address= 0*50) "